# Cannot import name 'Maze' from 'envs'

Tags: python, jupyter, maze

Running the following code in Jupyter and getting this error: cannot import name 'Maze' from 'envs'

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'c:\users\mycomputer\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages')

import gym
import numpy as np
from IPython import display
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from envs import Maze
%matplotlib inline
```

Comment: The `envs` module (whatever that is) does not contain an item named `Maze`.  Why did you think that it should?

Comment: Because the instructions from the course I'm taking show this exact code and I just copied the code.

Comment: you probably overlooked some initial instructions on installing the required modules.

Comment: This worked for me. --> To solve this issue, put all scripts of the homework in the same folder (most importantly the envs.py with the MDP_introduction script).

I also had to do add double \\ to the following and r before the path

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. `!pip install envs` (jupyter notebook code)
2. Take the script from GitHub page and save as `envs.py` in `site-packages/envs` folder.
3. `from envs.envs import Maze` (jupyter notebook code)

Comment: If you are using modern, normal Jupyter and to Google Colab, please use `%pip install envs` in a cell in your `.ipynb` file. When running installs inside notebooks, the use of an exclamation point can cause issues, see the second paragraph [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) for more about why use of the exclamation point in conjunction with `pip` or `conda` can be a problem. That problem was addressed by adding the modern magic install commands that insure the installation done inside a running `.ipynb` ...

Comment: <continued> file, take place in the environment backing the kernel underlying the notebook. See more about the modern magic install commands [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez). So ideally it is best to encouraging use of current best practices in your answers. And when you see use of an exclamation point with `pip` or `conda` convert it yourself going forward or at least be skeptical about how up-to-date the advice being provided is.

Answer (score -1):

The reason could be not having pygame
Do: *pip install pygame* in prompt and try again